# Sympy - plotting the result of a matrix calculation

Tags: python, plot, sympy

In my program, I'm using sympy to get an analytical expression for a set of constants (r, a, b and tau) then plot the graph of r as a function of l. Firstly, I define my constants as such:

```
import sympy
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

[z1, z2, z3, k2] = [1, 2, 4, 2 * numpy.pi]
l = sympy.Symbol('l')
r = sympy.Symbol('r')
tau = sympy.Symbol('tau')
base = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
```

I then define and calculate my matrices (where M2 is the transpose of [r, a, b, tau]):

```
M1 = sympy.Matrix([[-1, 1, 1, 0],
               [1, z1/z2, - z1/z2, 0],
               [0, sympy.exp(- 1j * k2 * l), sympy.exp(1j * k2 * l), -1],
               [0, - sympy.exp(- 1j * k2 * l), sympy.exp(1j * k2 * l), z2/z3],
               ])


M3 = sympy.Matrix([[1], [1], [0], [0]])

M2 = (M1 ** -1) * M3
```

I then try to plot this using:

```
sympy.plot(M2[0].subs(l, base), base)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev    \_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "matrix solver.py", line 47, in <module>
sympy.plot(M2[0].subs(l, base), base)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 1641, in plot
plot_expr = check_arguments(args, 1, 1)
  File "AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py", line 2302, in check_arguments
assert all(isinstance(e, Expr) for expr in exprs for e in expr)
AssertionError
```

Answer (score 1):

(The post is updated to include @OscarBenjamin's insightful comment.)

`.subs(l, base)` doesn't work. In general, sympy and numpy are quite hard to mix. Sympy works best well all expressions contain sympy symbols, integers and fractions.  Floats, by their imprecise nature, often make it very hard for sympy trying to achieve exact symbolic solutions.  Further, due to how sympy is incorporated into Python, an annoying [gotcha](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#python-numbers-vs-sympy-numbers) is Python converting an expression such `1/2` to `0.5` instead of to a sympy fraction.

Therefore, it is best to not `import numpy` in the part of the code that works with sympy. To avoid the problem with fractions, the tutorials suggest writing `z1 = sympy.S(1)`. `np.pi` is a float (about 16 digits), while `sympy.pi` is the symbolic constant `pi`. Replacing `1j` by `sympy.I` lets sympy do the calculations symbolically.

```py
import sympy

[z1, z2, z3, k2] = [sympy.S(1), sympy.S(2), sympy.S(4), 2 * sympy.pi]
l = sympy.Symbol('l')
r = sympy.Symbol('r')
tau = sympy.Symbol('tau')

M1 = sympy.Matrix([[-1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [1, z1 / z2, - z1 / z2, 0],
                   [0, sympy.exp(- sympy.I * k2 * l), sympy.exp(sympy.I * k2 * l), -1],
                   [0, - sympy.exp(- sympy.I * k2 * l), sympy.exp(sympy.I * k2 * l), z2 / z3],
                   ])

M3 = sympy.Matrix([[1], [1], [0], [0]])
M2 = (M1 ** -1) * M3
```

As the result contains complex numbers, the sympy way of plotting would use `sympy.re(M2[0])`. Sympy's plotting default uses an adaptive strategy to decide on the detail level, which can be slow for a plot with a lot of fine detail.

```
sympy.plot(sympy.re(M2[0]), (l, 0, 10), adaptive=False)
```

[image: sympy plot of real part]

Similartly, the imaginary part could be plotted using `sympy.im(M2[0])`.

[image: sympy plot of imaginary part]

To work with numpy and matplotlib, `lambdify` can convert sympy expressions to numpy functions:

```py
M2_0_np = sympy.lambdify(l, M2[0])
```

From then on, `M2_0_np()` can be used as a numpy function.

```py
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base = numpy.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
plt.plot(M2_0_np(base), base)
```

Plotting the function issues a warning *"ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part"*. So, only the real part of the function is plotted:

[image: plotting a sympy function with matplotlib]

More fanciful plots could be created combining real and imaginary part, e.g. via color.

Comment: You can also use `sympy.plot(sympy.re(sympy.cancel(M2[0])), (l, 0, 10))`. The `re` is needed for the plot to work. The `cancel` makes it faster (although it's still slow for some reason).

Comment: @OscarBenjamin Many thanks.  I updated the post.  The slowness is due to sympy's adaptiveness and the many spikes in the plot.